# Chance of getting X similar members from 2 random samples of distinct values?

Tags: probability

$A$ & $B$ each randomly selects $4$ distinct numbers from $1 - 10$. What is the chance of $A$ and $B$ choosing at least $3$ of the same numbers?

Example of a match:

$A$ selects $\{1, 4, 6, 7\}$

$B$ selects $\{1, 2, 6, 7\}$

In this case, the common numbers are $1$, $6$, and $7$.

> What is the chance of getting at least 3 similar numbers?

===

**edit**:

According to the suggestion below, I'm thinking the probability may be calculated this way: 
$$\frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{9} \cdot \frac{1}{8} \cdot {4 \choose 3}$$

That is: calculating the chance of getting a match the first time, the second time and the third time, then multiply with the number of ways to choose $3$ from $4$. But I'm not sure if it's flawed. I did a program to simulate it, and the result is bigger than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

What is the chance that $A$ gets at least $3$ numbers from e.g. the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$?

Can you find any essential difference if it concerns another subset having $4$ elements?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is this how you do it? (1/10) * (1/9) * (1/8) * (4C3) ? I'm calculating the chance of getting a match the first time, the second time and the third time, then multiply with the number of ways to choose 3 from 4.

Comment: The probability of $MMMN$ is $\frac{4}{10}\frac{3}{9}\frac{2}{8}\frac{6}{7}$ (here $M$ for match and $N$ for non-match). This also for $MMNM$, $MNMM$ and $NMMM$ so the probability of $3$ matches exactly is $\binom43\times\frac{4}{10}\frac{3}{9}\frac{2}{8}\frac{6}{7}$. Next to that the probability for $MMMM$ is $\frac{4}{10}\frac{3}{9}\frac{2}{8}\frac{1}{7}$ and must be added. A more direct route:$\left[\binom{4}{3}\binom{6}{1}+\binom{4}{4}\binom{6}{0}\right]\binom{10}{4}^{-1}=\frac{5}{42}$

Comment: Thanks. That matches my simulation result.